# Cleaning up URL column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, url, dataframe

I have the csv (or the dataframe) with the content as follows:

```
date          | URLs                                         | Count
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
17-mar-2014   | www.example.com/abcdef&=randstring           | 20
10-mar-2016   | www.example.com/xyzabc                       | 12
14-apr-2015   | www.example.com/abcdef                       | 11
12-mar-2016   | www.example.com/abcdef/randstring            | 30
15-mar-2016   | www.example.com/abcdef                       | 10
17-feb-2016   | www.example.com/xyzabc&=randstring           | 15
17-mar-2016   | www.example.com/abcdef&=someotherrandstring  | 12
```

I want to clean up the column 'URLs'  where I want to convert `www.example.com/abcdef&=randstring` or `www.example.com/abcdef/randstring` to just www.example.com/abcdef, and so on, for all the rows.

I tried to play around with `urlparse` library and parse the URLs to combile just the `urlparse(url).netloc` along with `urlparse(url).path`/`query`/`params`. But, it tuned out to be inefficient as every URL leads to completely different path/query/params.

Is there any work around for this using pandas? Any hints/ suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to parse anything, just truncate the string at the first '&'/'?' . Not clear from what you write if you want to keep the '/query' part either. This is simple string manipulation, barely even regex territory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's related with regex more than pandas, try to use pandas.apply to change one column.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def clear_url(origin_url):
    p = re.compile('(www.example.com/[a-zA-Z]*)')
    r = p.search(origin_url)
    if r:
        return r.groups(1)[0]
    else:
        return origin_url


d = [
    {'id':1, 'url':'www.example.com/abcdef&=randstring'},
    {'id':2, 'url':'www.example.com/abcdef'},
    {'id':3, 'url':'www.example.com/xyzabc&=randstring'}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print 'origin_df'
print df

df['url'] = df['url'].apply(clear_url)
print 'new_df'
print df
```

Output:

```
origin_df
id                                 url
0   1  www.example.com/abcdef&=randstring
1   2              www.example.com/abcdef
2   3  www.example.com/xyzabc&=randstring
new_df
id                     url
0   1  www.example.com/abcdef
1   2  www.example.com/abcdef
2   3  www.example.com/xyzabc
```

Comment: This should work. I was using apply function for something else. Could not think of using it with regex like you did. I will accept it once i check. Thanks.

Comment: Actually this didn't work :(  The structure of the urls are something like www.example.com/StringWhichContainsAlmosteverything followed by either ? or & and a random string. So I need to retains just tringWhichContainsAlmosteverything. Something like RegEx which ends with $ or &?

Comment: all of strings in your example seems to have '/' or '?', so I guess it may use  only a-z to extract word before that. For string not work, could you paste one example here?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by `regex` - filter all string created by `a-z` and `A-Z` between `www` and `.com` and also another string starts with `/`:

```
print (df.URLs.str.extract('(www.[a-zA-Z]*.com/[a-zA-Z]*)', expand=False))
0    www.example.com/abcdef
1    www.example.com/xyzabc
2    www.example.com/abcdef
3    www.example.com/abcdef
4    www.example.com/abcdef
5    www.example.com/xyzabc
6    www.example.com/abcdef
Name: URLs, dtype: object
```

Comment: I tried this initially. But the list of abcdef/xyzabc is huge :( . So, i am afraid, this could be a good fit :(

Comment: Not working too. The abcdef/xyzabc contains digits or special characters at times. However, the random strings start with either ? or & symbol.

Comment: Yes, but some string not contains `?` or `&` ?

Comment: I think `www.example.com/abcdef/randstring  `

Comment: www.example.com/abc.13&randstring and www.example.com/xyz.12.56?randstring are the examples. So I just want get rid of anything after ? or &.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130612/discussion-between-kingmakerking-and-jezrael).

Comment: Can you test `print (df.URLs.str.extract('([^?&]+)', expand=False))` ?